# Is there any documentation about smart phone browser screen sizes?

Tags: iphone, android, blackberry, mobile, smartphone

I've searched for some information on smartphone browser sizes so I can make a site that fits:

blackberry
iphone
android

But doesn't seem to be any hardcore dimensions floating around anybody know the info or has sources where I can find out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Screen size is typically included as part of the information in device capability databases such as [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/) or [DeviceAtlas](http://deviceatlas.com/).